# Problem with dash: Error in htmlDiv(...), could not find function "htmlDiv"

Tags: r, error-handling, plotly, plotly-dash

I get an error when running this code:

```
library(dash)

app <- Dash$new()

app$layout(
  htmlDiv(
    list(
      dccGraph("graph"),
      dccSlider(
        id = "slider",
        min = 500, max = 700, step = 50, value = 600,
        marks = list(500, 600, 700)
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Error:

```
Error in htmlDiv(list(dccGraph("graph"), dccSlider(id = "slider", min = 500,  : 
  could not find function "htmlDiv"
```

Now I see that htmlDiv is part of dashCoreComponents, but according to https://github.com/plotly/dash-core-components "As of Dash 2, the development of dash-core-components has been moved to the main Dash repo. This package exists for backward compatibility"

So I should not need to load `library(dashCoreComponents)` right? But even if I try, I would not be able to, because it is part of the `library(dash)` if I understand correctly. So it can't be because of this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting problem, exacerbated by the fact that `dash` was removed from CRAN last year, and perhaps further confused by the presence of a since-dropped [`dashR`](https://github.com/plotly/dashR) package. Your code seems legit from that perspective. However, looking at [`cran/dash/R/dashHtmlComponents.R`](https://github.com/cran/dash/blob/18e9bfa25389cc7027d1a54fcd7716aed8a99b41/R/dashHtmlComponents.R#L730) and its [`NAMESPACE`](https://github.com/cran/dash/blob/18e9bfa25389cc7027d1a54fcd7716aed8a99b41/NAMESPACE), it is defined but not exported. This seems like a bug-report, though it's not hard to get the idea that the concept of Dash for R is encouraged but not well supported.

The `app` can be made to work by `:::`-calling it.

```r
library(dash)

app <- Dash$new()

app$layout(
  dash:::htmlDiv(
    list(
      dccGraph("graph"),
      dccSlider(
        id = "slider",
        min = 500, max = 700, step = 50, value = 600,
        marks = list(500, 600, 700)
      )
    )
  )
)
# Warning in fn_summary$obj : partial match of 'obj' to 'objs'
# Warning in fn_summary$obj : partial match of 'obj' to 'objs'
# Warning in fn_summary$obj : partial match of 'obj' to 'objs'
# Warning in fn_summary$obj : partial match of 'obj' to 'objs'
# Warning in fn_summary$obj : partial match of 'obj' to 'objs'
# Warning in fn_summary$obj : partial match of 'obj' to 'objs'
# Warning in fn_summary$obj : partial match of 'obj' to 'objs'
# Warning in fn_summary$obj : partial match of 'obj' to 'objs'

app
```

[image: dash for R sample app]

(This is not a sustainable solution, however, it would be better to fix the package itself.)

Comment: Yeah after struggling with it for a while, I realised that dash has too little support, and I will likely be dealing with a lot more problems. So I thought it's probably better to use Shiny even though I like the look of Dash more.

Comment: I know the defaults in Dash can be more appealing in many areas, and I often feel that `shiny` defaults are just ... space-abusing and non-compact. Having said that, CSS is "free" (though at times cumbersome), so I'm confident somebody can comment here with suggestions for packages that do better in this regard (and perhaps even one that could mimic dash layout). Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! Maybe I should look for more packages.